# How to watch on a specific hset key with jedis

Tags: java, redis, watch, jedis

I would like to know if it is possible to set a watch on a specific key of a hset?
For example:
If I have an hset h1 with h1 = { hk1, hk2, hk3 } as keys of h1, is it possible to set a watch only on hk3 for instance and not on h1?
If it is possible, what would you write it, because I don't think it would work if I write it this way:

```
jedis.watch(hk1)
```

Since hk1 could exist in another set, but if I'm writing `jedis.watch(h1, hk1)` I assume that it will watch the whole set h1, which I don't want.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: I agree with @sazzad